# How is the wedge product in the Bianchi identity for torsion defined?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, curvature, exterior-algebra, connections

The torsion $\Theta:=\mathcal{D}\theta$ of a connection one-form $\omega$ for a principal $G$-bundle with respect to a solder(ing) form $\theta$ is given by $$\Theta=d\theta+\omega\wedge\theta$$ where $d$ is the exterior derivative and $\mathcal{D}$ is the exterior convariant derivative.

The Bianchi identity for torsion is given by $$\mathcal{D}\Theta=\Omega \wedge\theta$$ where  $\Omega$ is the curvature of the connection one-form.

My question is: in both of these statements, how is $\wedge$ defined? $\omega$ is a Lie-algebra-valued one-form and $\theta$ is a $V$-valued two-form, where $V$ is the representation space of a linear representation of the Lie group $G$, so how can we wedge these things together?

To make this more specific still (and to make clear my motivation for asking), **I'd like to understand how the "wedge" product explained at 1:07:25 here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j36o4DLLK2k is defined**; I'm struggling to understand Dr Schuller's explanation.

Comment: I wrote some notes on gauge theories this year that you can find here https://math-phys.group/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Gauge_Theories.pdf . In them I define what exactly is the wedge and prove Bianchi's Identity.

Comment: I don't (think I) have too much trouble understanding the definition of the "standard" wedge product (though the definition I know is different, though I imagine of course equivalent, to that in your notes) between an n-form and an m-form when those forms are both $C^{\infty}(M)$ valued (for M some smooth manifold), but in the lecture he seems to be explaining some other notion of a "wedge" product between forms that are differently-valued from eachother (one is $T_eG$ valued and the other $V$ valued), and it is *this* wedge product that I don't understand.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those notes by the way - they should come in very handy when I'm trying to understand how all of this relates to physics.

Comment: Yes, this is the notion of vector valued differential forms, in the first chapter explore those in detail, but for g-valued forms there is a little section in chapter three. And you are welcome! I'm happy to know something I wrote is being useful to someone!